# I Get This Typeerror:null Is Not An Object(Evaluating Scene.Props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-proptypes

I Get This Typeerror:null Is Not An Object(Evaluating Scene.Props).....what could I be doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Router} from "react-native-router-flux";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {scenes} from '../routes/home/scenes'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class AppContainer extends Component{
static propTypes={
    store:PropTypes.checkPropTypes()
}
render(){
    return(
           <Provider store={this.props.store}>
               <Router scenes={scenes}/>
           </Provider>      
        );
}
}
```

this is my scene.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Scene,Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import HomeContainer from '../home/containers/HomeContainers';

const scenes=Actions.create(
    <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="home" component={HomeContainer} title="home" initial/>
    </Scene>
)

export default scenes
```